# How to get value of Ini file from InputStream in Java?

Tags: java, http, inputstream, ini

I've developed a Web Service in Java, and my client will upload an *.ini* file to the service using the API which definition is something like

```
public Response PostStreamInfo(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathParam("UniqueId") String uniqueId, InputStream inputStream) 
        {
            /* my code here */
        }
```

Now I want to convert the inputStream back into .ini format, and retreive some value. However, all methods I found to get .ini content is read from *real file*, none of them talk about how to transfer from *inputstream*.

Is my goal possible? Because I don't want to *Store* the .ini file, *Read* it, and *Delete* it only for *1* value I need, I think that's a waste of time. Or should I just use Json format instead of InputStream to transfer the content? Thanks!

Comment: No, your task is not possible, because the [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class (which can be used to read "ini" files) doesn't support loading from `InputStream`, even though there is a perfect method for this: [load(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try another method to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with actual INI files or Java property files?

It looks like there's an [Apache class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/INIConfiguration.html) that you could use via an `InputStreamReader` and the `read` method for INI files.

If you're just dealing with Java property files, there are read methods that take InputStreams and also Readers.

Comment: I'm dealing with actual INI files. What I'm doing is reading an .ini file, convert to byte array and upload to the server through the API it provided.

Comment: The Apache class would work then. Do you understand how to convert an InputStream into a Reader?